# Factory Girl: NameError unintialized constant for one of the factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

So I have a strange problem where I have 3 factories declared out of which only 1 factory is intialized fine and rest of them are giving Unintialized constant.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.
I know this question has been asked so many times, but none of the answers are solving my problem.

here is my spec/factories/sample_factory.rb

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do

 factory :early_access do
     email {Faker::Internet.email}
 end

factory :login do
    email {Faker::Internet.email}
    password "password"
end

factory :user do
        display_name {Faker::Internet.name}
        email {Faker::Internet.email}
        username {Faker::Internet.username}
        password "password"
end
```

here is the model spec file spec/models/sample.rb

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'

describe EarlyAccess do

    it "has a valid factory" do
        FactoryGirl.build(:early_access).should be_valid
    end

    it "has a valid factory login" do
        FactoryGirl.build(:login).should be_valid
    end
end


    it "has valid factory user" do
        FactoryGirl.build(:user).should be_valid
    end
end
```

Out of these, only first one `early_access` passes and rest of them fail

```
.FF

Failures:

  1) EarlyAccess has a valid factory 2
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.build(:login).should be_valid
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Login
     # ./spec/models/sample.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) EarlyAccess has valid factory user
     Failure/Error: 
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant User
     # ./spec/models/sample.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have included factory_girl_rails in my spec_helper.

Comment: Do you have models Login and User? It tries to initialize the model based on the factory name. If the factory name is user, it will try to do `User.new`.

Comment: I don't think it's related to your problem, but you have a syntax error in your spec listing.  The 3rd `it` invocation isn't surrounded by a `describe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you have models EarlyAccess, Login, User defined
2. The models should be either manually required beforehand or conform to ActiveSupport::Dependencies autoloader convention (like located in app/models/login.rb app/models/user.rb respectively).

If you have these models located at some non-standard directory - require them manually or add the directories to config/application.rb config.autoload_paths array.